# Unit testing Mongoose models with KrakenJS

Tags: mongoose, mocha.js, kraken.js

I'm trying to unit test passport to log a user in.  Before the passport call, I'd like to insert a user using a Mongoose model.  I can insert the test user if I connect with Mongoose directly in the test.  However, I can't seem to use the application connection that Kraken creates in the beforeEach...

The call to save just hangs.

login.js test:

```
'use strict';
var app = require('../index'),
    kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    nconf = require('nconf'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    should = require('chai').should(),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    agent,
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'testing';


nconf.use('file', {
    file: process.cwd() + '/config/app.json',
    format: nconf.formats.json
});
var dbConf = nconf.get('databaseConfig')[env];

//mongoose
/*if (mongoose.connection.db) {
    return
} else {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://" + dbConf.host + '/' + dbConf.database);
    db = mongoose.connection;
}*/

describe('login', function () {

    var mock;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        kraken.create(app).listen(function (err, server) {
            mock = server;
            agent = request.agent(app);
            done(err);
        });
    });


    afterEach(function (done) {
        mock.close(done);
    });

    describe('User', function () {
        console.log('user time');
        before(function (done) {
            var user = new User({
                email: "user@user.com",
                firstName: "first",
                lastName: "last",
                password: "pass11",
                userName: 'someone'
            });
            user.save(function (err, user) {
                console.log('user: ' + user);
                console.log('err: ' + err);
                done();
            })
        });
        describe('Login test', function () {
            it('should redirect to /home', function (done) {
                agent
                    .post('/users/session')
                    .field('userName', 'someone')
                    .field('password', 'pass11')
                    .expect('Location', '/home')
                    .end(done)
            })

            after(function (done) {
                //User.remove().exec();
                return done();
            });

        })
    })


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with mongoose but I'm thinking the issue here is that things are not happening in the order you think they are happening. Here's a skeleton that has the same structure as your test:

```
describe('login', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log("beforeEach");
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        console.log("afterEach");
    });
    describe('User', function () {
        before(function () {
            console.log("before");
        });
        describe('Login test', function () {
            it('should redirect to /home', function () {
                console.log("test");
            });
            after(function () {
                console.log("after");
            });

        })
    })
});
```

If you run Mocha on this code, you'll get this output (funky spacing and all):

```
  login
    User
before
      Login test
beforeEach
test
        ✓ should redirect to /home 
afterEach
after


  1 passing (5ms)
```

Note how the `before` callback is called before your `beforeEach`. So your user is created, and the call to `save` is done, before you get a connection. It seems to me that changing your code so that the connection is created once, and only once before all your tests and closed only once after your tests would be the way to go. If you want to do this you need to change your `beforeEach` into `before` and `afterEach` into `after`.